# Is ado.net obsolete to use now?

Tags: ado.net

I'm creating an article related to ado.net. I want to verify if this is true or not because some people said that using ado.net in accessing database is obsolete now. And what's the difference between ado.net, entity framework, ORM, O/R, linq? Could someone enlighten me? thank you very much!

Comment: Everything else you've mentioned is built on ADO.NET (except LINQ.. however Linq-to-SQL is). It isn't obsolete, it is the foundation for working with databases in .NET. It certainly is the archaic way of accessing a database though.. given that all of the other technologies you've listed provide a much nicer interface over ADO.NET.

Comment: ..but definitely keep looking at your tutorial. You're bound to come across it again.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you don't know these answers, then why are you writing an article?

Comment: @JohnSaunders before I write an article, I wanted to know its correctness before disseminating such information and the opinion of readers such as you in your POV.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I thought so too. But I wanted to make sure of everything. I don't want to create an article with too many incorrect information. Besides, some articles or information spreading within the internet are not correct. It's better to make sure of everything.

Comment: Yeah, this is why I thought you should probably not write an article. Don't spread more garbage on the Internet.

Comment: Ohhh writing an article? I thought you wrote "reading an article". My second comment makes no sense. Now that I know what you're saying... I agree with John.

Comment: All right. I'll take note of all your suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both LINQ to Entities and Entity Framework use ADO.NET internally, so I wouldn't say it's obsolete.

There are certain cases when using ADO.NET is recommended more then L2SQL and EF, especially when performance really matters and you are able to sacrifice the ease of writing code in exchange to full control over what is send to database and when.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Entity Framework & O.R.M. using ADO.NET on back end. These framework are more optimized and efficient than the simple ADO.NET. While LINQ To SQL are more faster than ADO.NET because it doesn't use the functionalities of ADO.NET

Comment: Are you sure that linq to sql is more faster than ado.net